# Turn off and on column visibility

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with many columns and I'd like to provide the users with a drop down that allows them to select which columns they can see. I'm using the .Net 4 WPF DataGrid in a desktop application.

Does anyone know of an easy way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I do this as follows.

I derive from the grid an add an ICommand called HideShowColumnCommand that takes as its parameter a DataGridColumn (the one I want to hide or show) and hides the column if it is visible, and shows it if it is not.

Then I use a tricky context menu that I attach to the column header that has a tick that shows the column visible/hidden state..

The context menu looks like so

```
<ContextMenu
   ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Column.DataGridOwner.Columns}">
   <ContextMenu.Resources>
      <local:DataGridHeaderVisibilityToBooleanConverter
         x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
      <BooleanToVisibilityConverter
         x:Key="VisibilityOfBool" />

      <DataTemplate
         DataType="{x:Type DataGridColumn}">
         <ContentPresenter
            Content="{Binding Path=Header}"
            RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
      </DataTemplate>

   </ContextMenu.Resources>
   <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style
         TargetType="MenuItem">
         <!--Warning dont change the order of the following two setters
                   otherwise the command parameter gets set after the command fires,
                   not much use eh?-->
         <Setter
            Property="CommandParameter"
            Value="{Binding Path=.}" />
         <Setter
            Property="Command"
            Value="{Binding Path=DataGridOwner.HideShowColumnCommand}" />
         <Setter
            Property="IsChecked"
            Value="{Binding Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}" />
      </Style>
   </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

The converter like this

```
public class DataGridHeaderVisibilityToBooleanConverter :IValueConverter{
  #region IValueConverter Members

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
     try {

        Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;
        if (visibility == Visibility.Visible) {
           return true;
        }
        else {
           return false;
        }
     }
     catch { }
     return null;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
     throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  #endregion
}
```